# Proxy settings similar to Fiddler

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest, fiddler

I have a code that query to server

```
    try
    {
        using (var memoryStream = SerializeContentXml(query.Request))
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("some URL");
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers["api_key"] = RequestHelper.ApiKey;

            request.ContentLength = content.Length;
            using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(content.ToArray(), 0, (int)content.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }

            using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(query.Response.GetType());
                    var result = serializer.Deserialize(stream.BaseStream);
                    query.Response = (IBaseResponseModel)result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Status != WebExceptionStatus.Success)
        {
            var exceptionInfo = GetExceptionHierarchy(ex).Select(s => s.Message).ToArray();
            new ErrorLogger().Log(exceptionInfo);
        }
    }
```

My problem is:
Some queries loses content, so server receive empty content.
If fiddler is running and this option is checked [image], ALL queries completes successfully.
When fiddler is running, request proxy looks like
[image]

and default System Proxy settings looks like

[image]

My question is: How can I emulate this settings programmatically? I made lots of attempt to set request proxy manually, but without result.

Answer (score 0):

Having a proxy set is not what fixes your code.

Why are you closing `requeststream` and `stream` twice? You are doing so manually, and also via the `using` statement?

Why do you have a `try` with no `catch`?

Comment: I removed unnecessary calls.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code you're using. The current code doesn't compile and contains undefined variables (e.g. `content`)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can't show you the whole code because it's banned. That's wy I have showed you the fundamental part of the code without my own inner logic.

But I think, that my code is correct. It has been working during 1 year. The problems has appeared recently.
 
I'm so excited, that when fiddler is on and "Act as system proxy on startup" option is checked the code works perfect. Why is it so? Any ideas?

Comment: If you can't post the code you're having a problem with, it will be hard to get help.

Comment: My code is a part of large system we work on. I can't give you access to our system :(. "content" variable is xml serializable object. It size varies from 0.1 to 10 kB.

Comment: Tomorrow I will try to reproduce it out of our system.